# Second Order Nonhomogenous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While solving a problem I came upon this equation when coupling the subsystems, where h (height) is a distance and t is time. $$h_0 = h'_0 = h''_0 = 0$$

$$h'' = \frac{83.56158 \cdot \exp{(-1.139 \cdot 10^{-4} \cdot h)} - 0.2(h')^2}{8.518 - 5.747 \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot t + 1.880 \cdot 10^{-6} \cdot t^2} - 9.81$$

It sounds like a second order nonhomogenous ODE, but I've been trying to solve it by Undetermined Coefficients or Laplace Transform and having trouble due to the "different forms" the height comes in and it's division by a time polynomial.

Any advice would be welcome :)

Comment: What is $h_0 $?

Comment: Initial value, h(0) = h'(0) = h''(0) = 0

Comment: Then there is no solution

Comment: Oops, found the previous step where this specific problem was. I believe to have fixed the equation now and will try to solve again. Also edited the question in case someone could shed a light.

Comment: I'm trying to solve for h(t)

Comment: Yes. $h(t) = 0$ for all $t$. Sorry, didn't mean to delete my previous comment. You have too many ICs btw. $h''(0)$ is already determined to be $0$ by the ODE and your other two ICs